# Type predicate does not work on interfaces with common key

Tags: typescript

Why does the type guard `isMessage` fails to narrow the type in `handleResponse` function and can it be improved?

```
interface Message {
  message: string
}
interface ResponseResult extends Message {
  type: string,
  id: string,
}

function isMessage(data: Message | ResponseResult): data is Message {
  return true // in real world: Object.keys(data).join() === 'message'
}

const handleResponse = (response: Message | ResponseResult) => {
  if (isMessage(response)) {
    response // type is Message | ResponseResult, why is it not narrowed to Message?
  } else {
    response.id // Produces error: 'Property "id" does not exist on type "never"
  }
}

const response: Message = {message: 'ggrgr'}
handleResponse(response)
```

It will work if I remove `extends Message`, but I need this field on `ResponseResult` interface.

Comment: The compiler is telling you (via that `never`) that your `else` branch is unreachable: because your argument is of type Message either way `isMessage` will *always* be true (even if you don't put `return true` in your predicate). Just flip the predicate: instead of checking for `Message` do a predicate check for `ResponseResult`. All instances of the former are instances of the latter but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thanks, make sense! Jus a question regarding:  "All instances of the former are instances of the latter": did you maybe mean: "All instances of the latter[ResponseResult] are instances of the former[Message]"?

Comment: Correct: because ResponseResult extends Message all ResponseResults are Messages but not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

> It will work if I remove extends Message, but I need this field on ResponseResult interface.

This is exactly why you have `type is Message | ResponseResult, why is it not narrowed to Message?`. ResponseResult is also a Message.

## Suggested Fix

Recommend narrowing by the type that is a subset (i.e. ReponseResult).

## Fixed Code

```
interface Message {
    message: string
}
interface ResponseResult extends Message {
  type: string,
  id: string,
}

function isResponseResult(data: Message | ResponseResult): data is ResponseResult {
  return true // ...
}

const handleResponse = (response: Message | ResponseResult) => {
  if (isResponseResult(response)) {
    response 
  } else {
    response.message // Ok
  }
}

const response: Message = {message: 'ggrgr'}
handleResponse(response)
```